# Exception in thread "UI Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:

Tags: java, maven

The stacktrace is:

```
Exception in thread "UI Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-win32-3232 in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:123)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.<clinit>(OS.java:18)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:125)
        at com.sdm.hw.client.resource.RegistryBase.<init>(RegistryBase.java:16)
        at com.sdm.hw.client.resource.ImageRegistry.<init>(ImageRegistry.java:12)
        at com.sdm.hw.client.resource.StaticImageRegistry.<init>(StaticImageRegistry.java:12)
        at com.sdm.hw.client.resource.ResourceRegistry.getStaticImageRegistry(ResourceRegistry.java:89)
        at com.sdm.hw.client.resource.ResourceRegistry.getImage(ResourceRegistry.java:41)
        at com.sdm.hw.client.resource.ResourceRegistry.getImage(ResourceRegistry.java:33)
        at com.sdm.hw.client.action.HwAction.newImage(HwAction.java:190)
        at com.sdm.hw.client.action.HwAction.setImageName(HwAction.java:152)
        at com.sdm.hw.client.action.HwAction.localizeImages(HwAction.java:144)
        at com.sdm.hw.client.action.HwAction.<init>(HwAction.java:94)
        at com.sdm.hw.client.action.CloseAction.<init>(CloseAction.java:18)
        at com.sdm.hw.client.core.Application.createApplicationLevelActions(Application.java:554)
        at com.sdm.hw.client.core.Application.init(Application.java:146)
        at com.sdm.hw.client.HwMain.main(HwMain.java:81)
```

Entries in pom.xml is:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.sdm.hw</groupId>
            <artifactId>SecurityClient</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>x86</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32</groupId>
                </exclusion>


                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                </exclusion>
             </exclusions> 
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your stacktrace says "no swt-win32-3232 in java.library.path" and in your pom it's explictly excluded. Maybe you should try including it?!

**Update**:

Based on your comment, try:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sdm.hw</groupId>
        <artifactId>SecurityClient</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            </exclusion>
         </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
```

Comment: i tried : <dependency> <groupId>com.sdm.hw</groupId> <artifactId>SecurityClient</artifactId> <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> <inclusions> <inclusion> <artifactId>x86</artifactId> <groupId>org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32</groupId> </inclusion> <inclusion> <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId> <groupId>commons-codec</groupId> </inclusion> </inclusions> </dependency> but it is not working

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following and now its working:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.eclipse.swt.win32</groupId>
<artifactId>x86</artifactId>
<version>3.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```